# Lyx ignores document language settings

Tags: lyx, languages

I wish to create a pdf file in Lyx where the automatically inserted words such as "Part", "Author", "Abstract" and "Table of Contents" are replaced by their Polish equivalents.

After navigating to Documents -> Settings -> Language and setting the language to Polish, the problematic English words were indeed replaced by their Polish counterparts, but only in the main editing window - pressing "Ctrl+R" / exporting the document as pdf/html/dvi yields a file where the labels are still in English (exporting the document as .txt does make Lyx use the Polish language, but this is unsatisfactory for obvious reasons).

Setting the UI language to Polish didn't work and neither did changing the system language. The .lyx file does contain "\language polish".

Kubuntu 20.10 in English

LyX Version 2.3.6.1

Comment: Okay, I've solved this. If anyone has the same problem and ends up here trying to google a solution: go to Documents -> Settings -> Latex preamble and paste \usepackage[polish]{babel} . Then run sudo apt install texlive-lang-polish. Good luck

Comment: Hi, welcome. If you set the language to Polish in Document -> Settings -> Language, LyX will add `babel` for you I believe, so there should be no need to add it manually. You can see the generated LaTeX code via View -> Code Preview Pane. Choose "Complete source" or "Preamble only" in the dropdown in the pane itself. LyX may add the language option in the documentclass options (e.g. `\documentclass[polish, ...`), and later have `\usepackage{babel}`.